# Missing return statement, how can I fix?

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, webautomation

Goal: I have a class called "InvokeChromeTest" I'm extending to another class called "Base" to access chromedriver and data.properties. When running my code, I get the error:

*Error:(22, 3) java: missing return statement*

I am unsure how to fix this. Here is my sample code as follows. Please let me know what I can do to fix.

**src/test/java/loginPage/InvokeChromeTest**

```
package loginPage;

import credentials.ProfileCredentials;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import resources.Base;

public class InvokeChromeTest extends Base {

  @Test

  public WebDriver initializeDriver() {
    driver = initializeDriver();
    driver.get(dataProperties.getProperty("url"));
    ProfileCredentials p = new ProfileCredentials(driver);
    p.getAuthorize().click();
    p.getApiKey().sendKeys("testKey");
    p.getAuthCred().click();
    p.getCloseAuth().click();

  }

  @AfterTest
  public void teardown() {
    driver.close();
  }

}
```

**src/main/java/resources/Base**

```
package resources;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Base {

  public WebDriver driver;
  protected Properties dataProperties;

  public WebDriver initializeDriver() {
    // Create global property file
    dataProperties = new Properties();
    InputStream dataPropertiesInputStream = null;
    try{
      dataPropertiesInputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data.properties");
      dataProperties.load(dataPropertiesInputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String browserName = dataProperties.getProperty("browser");
    System.out.println(browserName);

    if (browserName.equals("chrome")) {
      WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
    } else if (browserName.equals("firefox")) {
      WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return driver;
  }

}
```

**src/main/java/credentials/ProfileCredentials**

```
package credentials;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class ProfileCredentials {

  WebDriver driver;


  public ProfileCredentials(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
  }

  private By authorize = By.xpath("//button[@class='btn authorize unlocked']");
  private By apikey = By.xpath("//div[@class='wrapper']//section//input");
  private By authorizecred = By.xpath("//button[@class='btn modal-btn auth authorize button']");
  private By closeauth = By.xpath("//button[@class='btn modal-btn auth btn-done button']");

  public WebElement getAuthorize() {
    return driver.findElement(authorize);
  }

  public WebElement getApiKey() {
    return driver.findElement(apikey);
  }

  public WebElement getAuthCred() {
    return driver.findElement(authorizecred);
  }

  public WebElement getCloseAuth() {
    return driver.findElement(closeauth);
  }
}
```

Comment: In InvokeChromeTest, initializeDriver method needs to return a WebDriver .

Comment: Your `initializeDriver` method in your `InvokeChromeTest` class indicates that it will return a `WebDriver`, but it never does.  (Unrelated, but that method also appears to infinitely recurse on itself...)

Comment: @CanBayar and @David, Thank you for the quick response. Do I just need to add `return driver;` inside of the InvokeChromeTest block on the bottom?

Comment: Sorry, meant inside of the initializeDriver block.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. "Base" and "InvokeChromeTest" had the same method name. This is why it was recursive.